# How to return a generics type without explicit specification of its argument?

Tags: java, generics

This is the Java 1.6 interface:

```
interface Foo<T extends Foo<T>> {
}
```

This is a factory, which is supposed to return `"Foo<Foo>"`:

```
interface Factory {
  <T extends Foo<T>> Foo<T> find();
}
```

Can't compile the factory class:

```
incompatible types; inferred type argument(s) java.lang.Object do not conform 
to bounds of type variable(s) T
[ERROR] found   : <T>Foo<T>
[ERROR] required: java.lang.Object
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

I can compile a factory class:

```
    class MyFoo implements Foo<MyFoo> { }

    Foo<MyFoo> foo = new Factory() {
        public <T extends Foo<T>> Foo<T> find() {
            return null;
        }
    }.find();
```

However, that as useful as an implementation of that interface can get, since the code inside `find()` has no means of discovering what `T` stands for in any particular invocation, and hence can not instantiate a `T`.

If your factory should only create instances of a particular type, give the factory a type parameter:

```
interface Factory<T> {
    T find();
}

class MyFactory implements Factory<MyFoo> {
    MyFoo find() { return new MyFoo(); }
}
```

If it creates instances of arbitrary type, pass the expected type to `find()`:

```
class Factory {
     <T extends Foo<T>> find(Class<T> clazz) {
         return clazz.newInstance();
     }
}

MyFoo myFoo = new Factory().find(MyFoo.class);
```

Finally, note that a factory creates objects while a repository finds them. Are you declaring a repository or a factory? Callers of your API might appriciate a clarification.

Comment: thanks for explanation, helps a lot. In my use case I want `Factory.find()` to return `Foo<Foo>`, always (it is mentioned in the question). How should I declare `find()` in this case?

Comment: `Foo<Foo>` is not a complete type, as `Foo` needs a type parameter. Maybe `Foo<?>`?

Comment: @Paulo you're right, `Foo<?>` works fine. If you post it like an answer I'd be happy to select it as the best one.